# Programmatically toggle Jenkins slaves online status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

What is the best procedure to toggle Jenkins slaves online status?
The JSON api for the slaves provides:

- offline
- temporarilyOffline

Is the assumption that `a job won't be assigned to a slave unless both those fields are false` correct?

What I've been doing is:

1) Toggle slave to temporarilyOffline = true

2) Spin up the slave machine

3) Launch the agent with /launchSlaveAgent POST call

4) Wait for the agent to be connected

5) Toggle the slave to temporarilyOffline = false

6) Periodically check whether the slave is idle, if it is, toggle temporarilyOffline = true, check that is still idle and if it is spin down the slave machine

This works most of the time.
Sometimes though I experience jobs that gets assigned to the slave and then fail with:

```
Cannot contact slave1: java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: /home/jenkins/workspace/Somejob at hudson.remoting.Channel@67acbe03:slave1: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Remote call on slave1 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
```

or similar.

I'm marking the job temporarilyOffline so that if it's connected to the agent it will stop accepting new jobs and I can shut down the machine safely. The problem occurs when a slave is started up and connected to the master via the agent, rather than on shutdown.

Is there any obvious problems in the approach? In particular, on step 4) if the slave is set `temporarilyOffline = true` then `offline` seems to stay true even when the agent is actually connected. So step 4) at the moment consist in looking at the slave console and search for the successfully connected string message (yuk).

I suppose that if I set the slave to `temporarilyOffline = false` then if I start the agent, then the `offline` field should toggle to `false` as soon as the agent is successfully connected.

I could switch to this approach but still does not explain why the exception occurs, in particular the bit I don't get is why a job would be assigned to the slave if the agent is not properly connected (as in, the `offline` flag should still be false and jobs should not be assigned to it).

**EDIT**: I've identified what was happening in that particular instance.
The agent would state to be connected with `Agent successfully connected and online` but immediately after it would add the following logs as well:

```
null
ERROR: Unexpected error in launching a slave. This is probably a bug in Jenkins.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.isRecoverable(SSHLauncher.java:1332)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1302)
```

So if my check on `Agent successfully connected and online` happened before `null` and the rest of the stacktrace would be printed out it would assume that the agent was successfully connected and toggle the slave online.

To work around the issue, once the script identifies that the agent is supposedly connected it waits x extra seconds and rechecks and won't toggle the slave online if the second check fails.

The outstanding question now is 'why that NullPointerException happens'?